# How to insert a child tag using XDocument and XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have this xml schema which I need to add a child tag to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PFA>
  <Entity id="123" action="add" date="04-Nov-2017"></Entity>
  <Entity id="125" action="add" date="05-Nov-2017"></Entity>
</PFA>
```

and the expected result is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PFA>
  <Record>
  <Entity id="123" action="add" date="04-Nov-2017"></Entity>
  <Entity id="125" action="add" date="05-Nov-2017"></Entity>
  </Record>
</PFA>
```

I have tried with this code:

```c#
var doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var record = new XElement("Record");
doc.Element("PFA").Add(record);
doc.Save("data.xml");
```

But my result is below. It has the closing tag, but it's missing the opening tag.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PFA>
  <Entity id="123" action="add" date="04-Nov-2017">
   
  </Entity>
  </Record>
</PFA>
```

---

Updated:

I tried this solution with `Elements`:

```c#
var doc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);
var record = new XElement("Record");
var pfa = doc.Element("PFA");
var entities = pfa.Elements("Entity");
entities.Remove();    // remove <Entity> from <PFA>
pfa.Add(record);    // add <Record> to <PFA>
record.Add(entities); // add <Entity> to <Record>
doc.Save(file.FullName);
```

But still the opening record tag is missing,

[image]

and the output becomes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PFA>
  <Record />
</PFA>
```

If I use `Element`:

```c#
var doc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);
var record = new XElement("Record");
var pfa = doc.Element("PFA");
var entities = pfa.Element("Entity");
entities.Remove();    // remove <Entity> from <PFA>
pfa.Add(record);    // add <Record> to <PFA>
record.Add(entities); // add <Entity> to <Record>
doc.Save(file.FullName);
```

The output becomes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PFA>
  <Entity id="123" action="add" date="04-Nov-2017"></Entity></Record>
  <Record><Entity id="123" action="add" date="04-Nov-2017"></Entity></Record>
  <Record><Entity id="125" action="add" date="05-Nov-2017"></Entity></Record>
</PFA>
```

Comment: The code you have posted does not create this invalid XML. Instead it creates a valid `<Record />` tag. Are you sure that is the XML you are currently getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually quite easy. You remove the `Entity` tags from the `PFA` tag, then add the new `Record` tag to the `PFA` tag and readd the `Entity` tags to the new added `Record` tag. The code might look like this:

```
var pfa = doc.Element("PFA");
IList<XElement> entities = pfa.Elements("Entity").ToList();
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    entity.Remove(); // Remove all the <Entity> tags from <PFA>
}
var record = new XElement("Record");
pfa.Add(record); // Add the new <Record>
foreach (var entity in entities) 
{
    record.Add(entity); // Add the <Entity> tags back to <Record>
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without removing entity tag? Because the actually file got more than 20 other tags inside PFA tag

Comment: You can use `Elements()` instead of `Element()` to get all the child of an element, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Elements. You don't need to identify them by each individual name.

Comment: I tried with `Elements()` but still can't get it expected result. When I debug it, during `pfa.Add(record)`, I can only see the closing tag for record. Not sure why. By the way, I have updated the expected result schema.

Comment: @Steve Check my update, I have changed it to use `Elements()` to get all the child element of an element. You can use it to "disconnect" all the `Entity` elements, then add your new `Record` and then readd all the `Entity` elements to the new `Record` element.